# Sample data from wearable devices

Tags: mapreduce, bigdata

I am a Graduate student currently doing a research on wearable devices. I have spent good number of hours on the internet looking for a sample dataset from wearable devices (such as fitbit, MS band, Smart watches etc) but I haven't been able to find an appropriate dataset.

I understand that it would be a proprietary property of the manufacturer, but I only need a sample for my research. I would be processing this raw data using Map Reduce techniques.

Can someone please suggest me if there is a way I can get a sample data from any wearable device?

Comment: Clock is present on any wearable devices, and can be easily reproduced! ;) . Seriously, this is not a SO question, you should ask directly to manufacturer...

Comment: Right. But I wanted to ask someone who has done a research on wearable devices before.  I felt SO was the best place to find them :). Most of the US medical data is available on https://www.cms.gov/ for research purposes. Unfortunately data from wearable devices still seem to be relatively a new concept and hence not available. May be if someone can guide me in getting such open source data.

Answer (score 0):

I am building the algorithm of the wearable device which harnessing multiple sensors. Basically, you can not do it without elaborate your vendor devices. Of course, we have to build our own algorithm but we can learn their algorithm as references.